# Set label width in pixel in tkinter, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

in tkinter when the label have some text the width unit is text unit, my question is simple, how can i set the label width using pixels even if the label contains some text?
I'm using the grid method to display the widgets.
Thank you for your help

Comment: You can assign a zero size image to it, then `width` will be in pixels.

Comment: how do i get a zero size image?

Answer (score 7):

You can assign a zero size image to it, then you can set the `width` and `height` of the label in pixels.

Below is a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

img = tk.PhotoImage() # zero size image
tk.Label(root, text='Hello', image=img, compound=tk.CENTER, width=200, height=100).pack()

root.mainloop()
```